# How to store row modification data in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema, audit

So I need to find a way to track modifications made to database rows. I'm thinking the best way to do this is to store object deltas for the row after the modification has been made to the row. So if I had this as a table:

```
CREATE TABLE global.users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  username text,
  password text,
  email text,
  admin boolean, --
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE global.users
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON COLUMN global.users.admin IS '';
```

So say I updated the username field from "support" to "admin", then I'd save a JSON object like, say:

```
{
    "username": ["support", "admin"]
}
```

associated with a specific row ID.

So my question is as follows: what's a nice way to organize these objects in Postgres? I'm currently debating between either a) having a deltas table for every existing table in the database (so this object would go into a table called `global.users_delta` or similar) or b) having a global `deltas` table which holds all deltas for all objects and tracks which table each is associated with.

I haven't really been able to identify any best practices for doing this sort of thing as yet, so even some direction towards preexisting documentation would be nice.

EDIT: An added requirement here is the issue of how to deal with the related data. So say, something belongs to a category, which is stored in another table. Usually that would be referenced by ID, so the delta would track the change in category ID's numeric value. That value needs to be labeled somehow, but that label can't necessarily be retroactively applied (in case the other linked value changes say). Should the labeled value be stored or should the raw value be stored? Or maybe both?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mysql`?

Comment: Btw: here is a complete solution for Postgres: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was actually suggested by SO, and I figured I'd leave it because this is a fairly generic database design question. Probably not necessary though.

Comment: If you want something different, how should it be different?  the path you are on leads to the question being closed as "too broad" or "opinion based"

Comment: @Jasen I added some more detail, but I'm not convinced it will necessarily make things less broad...

Comment: you've got audit trackinng on the linked table, isn't that enough?